# soap client parsing PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to parse a response from a webservice - the response seems to be valid XML, however, I can only parse attributes and somehow the objects do not have a representation for the text values - here is an example:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
<Product xmlns="http://com.etilize.spexlive" productId="1010043679">
    <category parId="135" name="Transparent &amp; Invisible Tapes" id="1009"/>
    <descriptions>
    <description type="1">Sparco Invisible Tape - 0.75&quot; Width x 1000&quot; Length - 1&quot; Core - Premium Acetate - Writable Surface - 12 / Pack - Clear
    </description>
    <description type="2">Sparco Invisible Tape</description>
    <description type="3">0.75&quot; Width x 1000&quot; Length - 1&quot; Core - Premium Acetate - Writable Surface - 12 / Pack -        Clear</description>
    </descriptions>
</Product>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can get the categoryId, Name and parId just fine but the Text values don't even seem to exist - Below is what I see when I do a var_dump on the soap Object - notice the descriptions:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [category] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1009
            [name] => Transparent & Invisible Tapes
            [parId] => 135
        )

    [descriptions] => stdClass Object
        (
            [description] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => 3
                        )

                )

        )
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What do you use to parse the response?

Comment: Last time I worked with SOAP from PHP, I specifically remember having issues parsing responses. Had to do with the options set on my client (soap version might have been one of them). I think I also had more success with certain message formats over others (I think I got rpc/encoded working).

Comment: I am using something like: 

    echo print_r($Response->category->name);

which works fine, however, any non-attribute information like the value of the description element "<description type="2">Sparco Invisible Tape</description>" is something I am having difficulty with - The object as cited above doesn't even show these values as existing

Comment: You definitely should use just print_r($Response...). No need for echo.